# Generar número aleatorio de palabras al azar

Tags: javascript

Lo que pretendo lograr es que al tener una lista de palabras predefinidas, poder lograr que aparezcan un número no definido de esas palabras de entre 3 a 10 aleatoriamente. Éste es un script que logré encontrar:

```js
var tad1 = new Array("#bre ","#bri ","#bri2 ","#brother ","#bro ","#bro2 ","#bru3 ","#bru4 ","#bru5 ","#bu ","#bu2 ","#bu3 ","#bu4 ","#bu5 ","#bu6 ","#bu7 ","#bu8 ","#bu9 ","#bu10  ","#bu11  ","#bu12  ","#bu13 ");

function tagAleatorio(){
  aleat = Math.random() * tad1.length;
  aleat = Math.floor(aleat);
  return tad1[aleat];
};

document.write (tagAleatorio());
```

Lo que pretendo es que en el documento aparezcan más de una palabra de la lista aleatoriamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes realizar una función para obtener la cantidad de elementos del array aleatoriamente.

```js
var tad1 = new Array("#bre ","#bri ","#bri2 ","#brother ","#bro ","#bro2 ","#bru3 ","#bru4 ","#bru5 ","#bu ","#bu2 ","#bu3 ","#bu4 ","#bu5 ","#bu6 ","#bu7 ","#bu8 ","#bu9 ","#bu10  ","#bu11  ","#bu12  ","#bu13 ");

function getRandomWords(min, max) {
//Obtiene numero aleatorio entre 3 y 10.
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
var words ="";
 //Obtiene palabras del array de acuerdo al valor obtenido como n.
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     words += tad1[Math.floor(Math.random() * tad1.length)];
  }
 return words;
}

document.write("Obtiene palabras aleatoriamente del array (3 a 10 palabras) : <br>" + getRandomWords(3, 10));
```

Comment: @Rubén gracias por la respuesta  tengo una duda mas sabes como añadir un salto de linea entre una funcion y otra ejemplo funcion1() <br/>funcion2()

Comment: Simplemente al final del resultado de la primera funcion concatena "<br>"...

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys . disculpa la pregunta se pueden poner funciones dentro de comas "funcion1()"

Comment: Para declararlas no, ya que serían consideradas como cadenas de caracteres, tal ves te refieres a como se pueden llamar desde html : <a href=""  onmouseover="mifuncion()"></a>

Comment: El autor de la respuesta es @Jorgesys, no yo. En cualquier caso, si te refieres al editor de código, ¿ya intentaste oprimir la tecla Intro?

Comment: El código no funciona bien, lo he probado y ha devuelto 11 palabras : "Obtiene palabras aleatoriamente del array (3 a 10 palabras) :
#bru5 #bu13 #bu8 #bu #bu2 #bri #bru3 #bu13 #bru5 #bru3 #bru3" . El motivo es lo que explica Mariano.

Comment: +1 @Mariano tienes razón Mariano lo que tenía era: var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 3; , Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Para generar letra al azar debemos generar primero un numero que se encuentre en dentro del alfabeto ejemplo del 0 al 25

```
var numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25); //el numero de 0 a 25 el alfabeto
```

Una vez que tengamos el numero generamos le letra agregando 97, entendiendo que la numeracion del ASCII empieza desde 97

```
var letraAleatoria = String.fromCharCode(97 + numero);
```

ahora mezclamos todo esto con un for para tener una palabra aleatorioa

```js
var palabra = ""
 for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){   
    let numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25); 
    let letraAleatoria = String.fromCharCode(97 + numero);
    palabra = palabra + letraAleatoria;
 }
 console.log(palabra)
```

Comment: un poco mas estensa la explicacion estaria muy buena  gracias

Answer (score -1):

Tu código está bien para obtener una palabra aleatoria.

Solo falta llamar a ese mismo código dentro de un bucle que concatene palabras. Bucle controlado por una variable aleatoria elegida entre un mínimo y máximo.

```js
var tad1 = new Array("#bre ","#bri ","#bri2 ","#brother ","#bro ","#bro2 ","#bru3 ","#bru4 ","#bru5 ","#bu ","#bu2 ","#bu3 ","#bu4 ","#bu5 ","#bu6 ","#bu7 ","#bu8 ","#bu9 ","#bu10  ","#bu11  ","#bu12  ","#bu13 ");

function tagAleatorio(){
  aleat = Math.random() * tad1.length;
  aleat = Math.floor(aleat);
  return tad1[aleat];
};

function palabrasAleatorias(min, max) {
  // Valor aleatorio entre min y max ambos inclusive
  var numPalabras = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
  // Añadir palabras usando la función del OP
  var palabras ="";
  for (i = 0; i < numPalabras; i++) {
     palabras += tagAleatorio();
  }
  return palabras;
}

document.write (palabrasAleatorias(3, 10));
```

Comment: Quizás la votante del negativo podría comentar qué le parece mal ;)

Comment: interezante forma de lograrlo se les agradese